# Can we analyze "to protect his country's southern border" as the non-finite clause of "the military"?

Tags: grammar

> Trump announced yesterday that he intended **[** to deploy the military **to
>   protect his country's southern border** **]**

I want to know whether the bold part can be analyzed as the non-finite clause of **"the military"**.

I guess it can be in the same way as in "I want him **to lend me some money**"

(Here, **"to lend me some money"** is modifying **"him"** as a non-finite clause)

So, I think the sentence can mean, according to my analyzing, **"Trump announced yesterday that he intended to deploy the military so that the military can protect his country's southern border"**.

Is my analyzing correct?

Comment: The sentence can be parsed in two different ways: (1) *He intended to deploy the military **in order to** protect the border*, and (2) *He intended to deploy the military **that would** protect the border.* Is that what you're asking? In other words, it's not clear if *he's* protecting the border by deploying the military or if it's *the military* that has been tasked with protecting the border. The difference is subtle, but it exists. Both interpretations are possible from the existing syntax; it's ambiguous.

Comment: @JasonBassford Yes, you got the point I'm taking of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the sentence:

> Trump announced yesterday that he intended to deploy the military to protect his country's southern border.

The specific interpretation of the sentence is ambiguous, as it can be parsed in two different ways.

The reason it's ambiguous is because of the second *to* and what follows after it. Either it applies to Trump's intention or it applies specifically to the military:

> 1. He intended to <sup>deploy the military</sup> to protect his country's southern border.
> 2. He intended to <sup>deploy the military to protect his country's southern border</sup>.

---

In order to make the intended meaning explicit, it needs to be rephrased. Here are some possible changes in wording. In each interpretation, I provide a more significant rephrasing first followed by one where all I do is insert a couple of words.

> 1. a) Trump announced yesterday that he intended to protect his country's southern border by deploying the military.
>    b) Trump announced yesterday that he intended to deploy the military ***in order to*** protect his country's southern border.

In this interpretation, it's explicitly *Trump* who is protecting the border, and it's the deployment of the military that is the mechanism by which this is done.

> 2. a) Trump announced yesterday that he intended to deploy the military and task it with protecting his country's southern border.
>    b) Trump announced yesterday that he intended to deploy the military ***that would*** protect his country's southern border.

Here, it's the *military* that is protecting the border, and it's Trump who is ordering it to do so.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's an adverb phrase that modifies "deploy".   It's the *reason* for the deployment.  The military is the direct object, as the thing being deployed.

In this it's similar to something like:

> I'm going home **to pick up my kids**.

"Home" isn't modified by "to pick up my kids".   It's just the object of the verb "go".  The rest is the *reason* for me going home.

---

Still, I'm not sure where you might draw the line between *adverb phrase* and *object complement*.  For example:

> I asked her to marry me.

Certainly you could say "to marry me" complements "her", but you could also say that "to marry me" is the direct object, and "her" the indirect object.  After some point, unless you are a professional linguist, these terms only have meaning on an English test, and only mean what your professor says they mean.

Comment: So, to summarize, you saying you don't agree that the original sentence can be analyzed as "Trump announced yesterday that he intended **[to deploy the military to protect his country's southern border]**", but "**[Trump announced yesterday that he intended to deploy the military]** to protect his country's southern border"?

Comment: @Floret  I'm not sure what "analyze" means to you.  If you really break the sentence into its components, you'd start by separating "Trump announced" from the rest.

Comment: Okay, then, to say differently, isn't there any context in which the bold part in the original sentence can be thought of as a complement of **"the military"**? Doesn't it make any sense if we regard **"the bold part"** as complementing **"the military"**?

Comment: Sorry, I should have used the grammatical term of "non-finite clause". I just edited my question.

Comment: @Floret  Sure, it's possible, but not as written.  For example, *"Donald Trump issued a command for the military to protect the southern border"*.  In this case "to protect the southern border" complements "command".   Maybe something like, *"Ours is the military to protect the southern border"* ... but it's a stretch.